# Extend property of interface without declaring a new interface

Tags: typescript

I'm working with a JSON API in TypeScript. Often part of the JSON API is the same except for an additional field. I'm trying to find a shortcut that doesn't include creating an additional named interface just for that property. I often have to do something like the following:

```typescript
interface ICar extends IVehicle {
  headlights: IHeadlights
}

interface IHeadlights extends ILights {
  beam_strength: number
}
```

In TypeScript you can do something like this but then you lose the advantage of extending an already declared interface:

```typescript
interface ICar extends IVehicle {
  headlights: {
      beam_strength: number,
      color: string,
      bulb: string
  }
}
```

Ideally I would like to combine the two so I could so something like this:

```typescript
interface ICar extends IVehicle {
  headlights: ILights {
    beam_strength: number
  }
}
```

Or something like this:

```typescript
interface ICar extends IVehicle {
  headlights extends ILights {
    beam_strength: number
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do something like this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `IVehicle` and `ILights` are existing types, you could use [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) to create a new subtype of `ILights` without giving it its own name:

```
interface ICar extends IVehicle {
  headlights: ILights & {
    beam_strength: number
  }
}
```

I don't really understand *why* you don't want to just give it a name; extended interfaces are a bit nicer to inspect in your editor than intersection types, so all else being equal I'd prefer to extend an interface.  But it's up to you.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks! When modeling large JSON APIs, naming gets hard & seems to add a lot of confusion & lines of code. We're using the JSON API spec http://jsonapi.org/ Typically the models are 99% identical but contain an additional property buried down a bit. With extends we need to create a bunch of named interfaces just to add one property. Maybe there is some very different better way as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the type intersection operator `&`? This would look like:

```
interface ICar extends IVehicle {
    headlights: ILights & {
        beam_strength: number;
    }
}
```